# Checking null in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have the below code which is not working properly. Can someone please look at it and tell me what can be happening here. When I read the object value in an alert it shows as null but when I test the value of the object by IsNull the object does not behave as null.

```
' This object comes out null in alert
         alert(ROSnode.selectsinglenode("./root/allnegative"))

           ' The same object comes out as not null in this if
           if not IsNull(ROSnode.selectsinglenode("./root/allnegative")) then
            alert("Not showing null here")
            templateDSO.selectsinglenode("//rosv2").appendchild   ROSnode.selectsinglenode("./root/allnegative")
          else
          alert("It is null")
          end if
```

Thanks

Comment: try `if ROSnode.selectsinglenode("./root/allnegative") is nothing then ...`

Answer (score 0):

isnull works only if the varaiable is stored as Null ,you can check if the value is not equal to blank like if ROSnode.selectsinglenode("./root/allnegative") <> "" then or if ROSnode.selectsinglenode("./root/allnegative") is nothing then